I am trying to check the user status of openIDM, throught restAPI's, i am geeting an error
How to fix this issue? And this is my IDM url (http://idm.example.com:8080/admin/#resource/managed/user/list/). Can anyone  help me with this one?
I'm making a GET request to the ForgeRock IDM API at the endpoint http://idm.example.com:8080/openidm/managed/user/skyblue123?_fields=accountStatus. This request aims to retrieve the accountStatus for a user with the ID skyblue123. To authenticate, you have included headers such as x-openidm-username and x-openidm-password, both set to openidm-admin, along with accept-api-version set to resource=1.0 to specify the version of the API resource.
Despite these authentication details, the server has responded with a "404 Not Found" error, indicating that it could not locate the resource.
The "404 Not Found" response suggests several possibilities. First, the user ID skyblue123 may not exist in the IDM system. This can be confirmed by checking the user list in the IDM admin interface or by querying all users. Another possibility is that the openidm-admin user lacks the necessary permissions to access the accountStatus attribute for skyblue123. It’s also essential to verify that the URL structure is correct and matches the expected API endpoint format.
The correct URL should follow the pattern
http://idm.example.com:8080/openidm/managed/user/<user-id>?_fields=accountStatus

where <user-id> is replaced with the actual user identifier. I need a solution.
